JS: Proper way to split backend communication (express api and socket.io)
I want to create a browser game and thought about the project structure and got a little confused myself how to manage this.
I thought about using vite react for the frontend using axios to post to a backend server running express. This should simply handle user data like the login and database related stuff by calling backend api's.
The game itself then should be drawn ontop of a canvas inside the vite react client and create a socket.io connection to a different port inside the express backend.
So I would want to split the database related backend from the socket.io related stuff inside the same backend server using different ports.
Would this be the proper way to manage this? Because i am a little confused. I used to create my socket.io backend server the following way:
import { createServer } from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

const httpServer = createServer()
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors {
        origin process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'  false  ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000']
    }
})

io.on('connection', socket = {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected`)

    socket.on('message', (data) = {
        console.log(data)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () = {
        console.log('A user disconnected')
    })
})

httpServer.listen(3500, () = {
    console.log('Listening on port 3500')
})

which I have updated now to use express because I want to use it also to receive axios post/get requests to api endpoints to handle database related stuff.
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use('/', require('./routes/authRoutes'))

const port = 8000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Backend server is running on port ${port}`))

Question: How could I manage to use the same express backend to listen for database api calls and for socket.io emit messages?
Would appreciate any kind of suggestions.
